# Why a text element with shadow appears blurry when the application is executing

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I've been programming an application using WPF Technology in VS2013.

When I run the program, text quality of the shaded text is lower than what I see using the design mode in Visual Studio.

Below is what happened in picture:

[image]

When this happens, smaller Persian or English characters (in 7,8,9 px text size) are difficult to read for users the in the interface.

Why does this seem better in Debug mode, and how is it possible to have the same quality in the final application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This rendering blur occur due to the text metrics used by WPF while formatting text.

`TextOptions.TextFormattingMode` is your solution, this will indicates which font metrics to be used while the TextFormatter lays out text.

so set this attached property on the text elements to enable the same

eg

```
<TextBlock Text="Test" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" />
```

By setting the value to `Display` you'll receive the font rendered with the best GDI compatible font metrics with minimum blur

apart from above you can also make use of `RenderOptions.EdgeMode` which will affect the rendering of non text elements

also `RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode` will help you to prevent blurring when zooming etc.

eg

```
<Grid RenderOptions.EdgeMode="Aliased" RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="NearestNeighbor">
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
        <TextBlock Text="Test" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"/>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

with combination of above you can ensure most crisp UI rendering

also it seems like you are using drop shadow so perhaps include `RenderingBias="Quality"` in the drop shadow to improve the shadow quality

```
    <TextBlock Text="Test" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display">
        <TextBlock.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect RenderingBias="Quality"/>
        </TextBlock.Effect>
    </TextBlock>
```

more info

[TextOptions.TextFormattingMode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/text/archive/2009/08/24/wpf-4-0-text-stack-improvements.aspx)

[RenderOptions.EdgeMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.edgemode)

[RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.renderoptions.bitmapscalingmode)